# What is the meaning of "val Class.Something(2,_) = doSomething()"?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I am reading Lihaoyi's presentation of his parser combinators framework while knowing only the basics of Scala.
I came across this line that I don't understand at all:

```
val Parsed.Success(2, _) = parse("1+1", expr(_))
```

Coming from Java, it looks weird. Anybody knows what it does?
Thanks in advance.

https://www.lihaoyi.com/fastparse/

What would be the equivalent in Java?

Comment: It is a form of pattern matching. It means that the result of `parse("1+1", expr(_))` should be a `Parsed.Success` whose first element has to be a **2** _(the result of `1+1`)_ and the second component can be of anything as it will be ignored. The match is valid from the type inference perspective, but it nay fail at runtime _(e.g. if instead of `1+1` you type `1+2`)_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scala knows *Extractor Objects* - see [docs.scala-lang.org](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html)

They are mostly used for pattern matching - see [docs.scala-lang.org](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html)

So this can be used with `val`s:

```
val customer2ID = CustomerID("Nico")
val CustomerID(name) = customer2ID
println(name)  // prints Nico
```

Your example will throw a `scala.MatchError` if the parser would not work.

Try `val Parsed.Success(2, _) = parse("1+2", expr(_))` // should be 3

Comment: It doesn't really use extractor object, but the `unapply` from the companion object generate for the case class `Success` (as for any case class).

Comment: "An extractor object is an object with an `unapply` method" - companion (of a case class) seems like an example of extractor object.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers explained what this is technically, but why did the author of fastparse write

```
val Parsed.Success(2, _) = parse("1+1", expr(_))
```

where we see no variable is actually bound in the sense of being usable after this statement executes? This kind of looks like a side-effect returning unit. I believe the author is deploying this technique as an alternative to assertion

```
assert(parse("1+1", expr(_)) == Parsed.Success(2, 3))
```

but they want to emphasise they do not care about the `index` value of `Success[+T](value: T, index: Int)` which they cannot do using regular `assert`

```
assert(parse("1+1", expr(_)) == Parsed.Success(2, _)) // error: missing parameter type for expanded function
```

Answer (score 2):

Function `parse` is returning a `Parsed[T]`, which is matched against the extractor of the `Success` case class (inside the object `Parsed`).

It could be rewritten as:

```scala
parse("1+1", expr(_)) match {
  case Parsed.Success(2, _/*index*/) => ???
}
```

The previous make it obvious that it's not an exhaustive match (and so the `val` pattern would raise a `MatchError`).

Could also be used as bellow, to be more explicit and avoid `MatchError`.

```scala
val res: Option[(Int/* value */, Int/* index */)] = 
  Parsed.Success.unapply(parse("1+2", expr(_)))
```